# Array filter with bind value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, bind, return-value

Good evening,

I wanted to make a function that would return a filtered array that did not contain the values passed to this function as `arguments`.

This is the code I have been using for this, but it does not return the filtered array as expected, although, if I console.log all the passed parameters to the filtering callbackfn, it sees them as I did bind the `arguments[i]`-th element.

Here the code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
    arr.filter(seeker.bind(null, arguments[i]));
  }
  return arr;
}

function seeker(arg, value, index, array){
  console.log(arg, value, index, array);
  return value !== arg;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

And this is a screenshot of the console.logs:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not alter the original array, it returns a new array with any changes made. You'll need to assign this new array back to the `arr` variable.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
    arr = arr.filter(seeker.bind(null, arguments[i]));
  }
  return arr;
}

function seeker(arg, value, index, array){
  return value !== arg;
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: I feel so dumb and lucky at the same time. Thank you sir. Thank you.